# Objectify GAE/J Google App Engine: Understanding asynchronous load

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, asynchronous, objectify

I'm new to Objectify and I don't understand something (a stupid thing).
I'm building a Restful Web Service (with restlet) and I'm creating a JSON response. So:

```
Party party;
    for(Ref<Game> jref : party.games)
    {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        try{
            Game gAux = jref.get(); //If the value ref is not load, the excetion throws
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e)
        {
        //Is asynchronous
            jref = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().ref(jref);
        }

        serializeGame(jref.get(), object);
    }
```

Ok, the code is very simple, I get a Game object and then I serialize it to JSON object, then I send the response.
But I don't understand how the asynchronous `load()` work.

If `load().ref(jref)` is asynchronous:

1. What does it return? So, if `load().ref()` returns a empty object o a "future" object:
2. What's happend when I use the object? (I use a null values object?, a "still wating" object)?
3. How do I know the object is ready? (some listener, handler?) to use it?
4. Extra: If there isn't any manner to know when the object is ready, how do I load a ref synchronous?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/8dLAbSWJVB4

The "short answer" is that Ref/Map/List are asynchronous facades that synchronously block when you try to materialize a POJO.  Just like Future.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I was thinking about differents Threads and concurrent programming: when I use load.ref() I thought that a new thread is created, with another context and this thread loads the data  (Well, maybe Objectify uses a thread to execute this queue, but now it is not the question). Thank you.